# Condiciones en python

Tags: python

Quiero hacer tres condiciones con if para que, dependiendo del valor de **count** me imprima una cosa u otra. Tengo el siguiente código pero no consigo que me lo imprima:

```
x = "string"
count = x.count("i")

if count == 1:
 print ("1")
if count == 0:
 print ("0")
if count < 1:
 print ("+1)
```

Comment: ¿cómo lo ejecutas? Debería entrar en `if count == 1`. Nótese de todos modos que es más claro hacer una estructura de `if / else if / else`, para no dejar ninguna condición fuera.

Comment: Te falta cerrar comillas en el último print. Como no sea eso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que se me ocurre es que no hayas cerrado las comillas en el ultimo `print`:

```
if count < 1:
 print ("+1")
```

De todos modos, no entiendo por que querrías un `count < 1` si ya tienes una condición que hace lo mismo con `count == 0`

Comment: las comillas si las tenia bien en mi codigo no hay problema por eso pero el problema venia porque tenia mal el signo del mayor que